# Why does my page make me scroll twice om mobile?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, shopify

I'm having an odd issue that is causing people to have to scroll twice, or the page becomes stuck on mobile devices less than 600px wide. I've tried the following without any luck. I am an absolute beginner, so please forgive my ignorance. The page is

https://neverthirst.myshopify.com/pages/eoy2019

```
.ClassForEntirePage{
height:100%; overflow-y:hidden;
}
```

Would you please help me figure out where I'm going wrong?

Thanks for any help on this!!

Comment: Why are you hiding overflow y?

Comment: What do you mean by "users have to scroll twice?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a property `overflow-y: scroll` in one of your CSS file at `html` tag.

you need to remove that property from that if possible. otherwise you have to override that property by applying property using `!important` like below:

put this css code to your custom css file.

```
html {
    overflow-y: initial !important;
}
```

I hope this will works fine for you.

Thank You...